# Mixing identifier parse with whitespace parser

Tags: parsing, haskell, text-parsing

The parsing library has the function *identifier* and the function *whitespace*:

```
identifier :: Parser Char String

whitespace :: Parser Char ()
```

The function *identifier* made the parsing of an identifier, but don't discard the whitespaces on the input text. So, we have the *withespace* function, that consumes all whitespaces from an input.

I was wondering if I could mix this two functions into one. Just like:

```
identifier' :: Parser Char String
```

However, I'm new in Haskell and don't know how I do that exactly. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: `identifier' = identifier <* whitespace` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with [**`(<*) :: Applicative f => f a -> f b -> f a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--42-) that will here run the first parser, then the second and return the result of the first parser, so:

```
identifier' :: Parser Char String
identifier' = identifier <* whitespace
```

This is equivalent to:

```
identifier' :: Parser Char String
identifier' = do
    idf <- identifier
    whitespace
    return idf
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! I was trying to use <*>, but now I see that doesn't even make sense what I was trying to do.

Comment: @GustavoPresoti: `identifer <* whitespace` *could* be written equivalently as `const <$> identifier <*> whitespace`, where `const` just selects the result of the first parser and discards the other, but `<*` is simpler here. It’s similar for other `Applicative` shorthand operators like `*>` and `<$`. You would use the `<*>` operator with the `Applicative` pattern of `function <$> parser1 <*> … <*> parserN` when you have multiple parsers and you want to combine their results with a pure function. That will often be a data constructor for the type that you’re parsing.